# How to show DialogFragment after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

could you tell me how can I show `DialogFragment` after screen rotation? I've got `BroadcastReceiver` in parent activity and when receiver receive something I call function `showDialog()` from `GetHelpFragment`. Until the screen is rotated everything works fine but after rotation I've got `RuntimeException` caused by this:

```
public void showDialog() {
   new AutomaticDialogFragment().show(getFragmentManager(), "AutomaticDialogFragment");
}
```

And that is what I have in the `Activity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() { 
        @Override 
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
            String action = intent.getAction(); 
            if (action.equals(GetHelpFragment.INTENT_SHOW_DIALOG)) { 
               getHelpFragment.showDialog();
            }         
        } 
    };

    IntentFilter ifilt = new IntentFilter(GetHelpFragment.INTENT_SHOW_DIALOG); 
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, ifilt);

}

@Override 
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

Why it works as it works currently? How can I fix it?

Thanks for help.